# Micro frontend application

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application

I have 1 project which is divided into multiple SPA, I have 5 SPA, written in 2 in Angular, 2 in react and 1 in vue js. Now I have an integrated server which will serve the different files as per routing. I need to share the data from one app to another with least interaction of database. This is a scenario of micro frontends. Hope this clears my problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can share common store between them . for eg: mobx is compatible with all of them

Comment: Where does this mobx stores data, in localstorage or cookies or somewhere else? How does it share data among different apps? these are the most important question before implementing into the project.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways with which you can share data:

1. URL: Query Params/Path Params (Only for small data like ID, filters, etc.)
2. Session Storage: Use this only if you are not navigating to other tab/window
3. Local Storage: Most convenient and preferred way

Of course, if you are persisting state to Local Storage, then you have to handle flushing of the state by yourself when the user logs out.

This is a bit painful process to handle. You will have to write code to manage serialization and deserialization of JSON to Local Storage. To ease this, it is better if you have the same state management solution across all micro-apps. I recommend the use of Redux/MobX to do this. But if you are using Redux for React, Ng-Rx for Angular and Vuex for Vue, then you will not have any ready-made solution.

Also, when you are saving the state to Local Storage, either debounce it or do it lazily with little delay for performance reasons.

We are using micro-frontends for last two years and we use the mix of Local and Session storage to do our things. Luckily, for all the apps we use Redux, even with Vue, and that allows us to use [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage).

You can also use Cookies but it is generally better to avoid them.

Comment: The data which will be saved in localstorage may be jwt token. I think it's not a good idea to have the token and other important stuff on localstorage. i can do some manipulation, but is there a way which won't expose token on the client side?

Comment: @Amit, It is JWT means it is encrypted. Nobody can read it without a decryption key. So you need not worry about that. Also, the moment token is sent to the client, you store it or not, the token is anyways exposed.

Comment: I understand that JWT is encrypted and can be decrypted by decryption key, but it is vulnerable to XSS attack because the sensitive data is open, means it can be copied and made requests to our websites which we may not know. Third party JS library can be a way. I am not in support of storing JWT or any data like this should not be saved in local storage. Any other thing which can replace local storage then it would solve my problem. If I am wrong, please tell me. And please suggest any other option.

Comment: Yes @Amit, I agree. If you are using third-party, then you are open to XSS. In this case, there is just no way you can use anything other than cookies. And, your cookies should be httpOnly cookies. You will have to live without JWT on client-side. There is no other way without involving a server into picture.

Comment: Yes, I am still in search of some better approach. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @IoneWolf Store your Tokens in Cookies with `httpOnly`. That way they are not prone to XSS and they are transparently set by the browser, i.e. within a single session they will be available to all your different SPAs.

Comment: Didn't understand how attaching a token with Cookies will not be prone to XSS. If as a attacker, I can inject my JS in. I can talk to any resources with server and browser will happily attach the Cookie (token). In any case I have access to Token, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @prabhatojha Use secure cookie along with `httpOnly` flag. That prevents it reading from client-side. Also, CORS + CSRF mechanism will prevent cross domain issues.

Answer (score 1):

1st, Custom element creation
I have worked for micro-front-end elements base architecture with @Angular/element module. As I worked, I used bellow flow[image]

For code, I have followed [build-a-micro-frontend-application-using-angular-elements](https://www.agiratech.com/build-a-micro-frontend-application-using-angular-elements).
Here it will provide you elements like native html elements.

2nd, Another good approach is to use library feature in angular. You can write your components, directive or pipe, then publish them or use them into other project directly. In this approach again you can reuse the same code.

3rd, We can use i-frame, but now days it is causing lot of security issues from browser.

Comment: In your situation, i-frame, Index DB, session storage, local storage & cookies can help you. Single sign-on (SSO) is also a good technique for common login system.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a frontend event bus like [EEV](https://github.com/chrisdavies/eev). Your application shell would be responsible for creating a shared event listener. Then each micro-frontend could emit events on that shared channel.

You could also use an RxJS Subject as a message bus within your App Shell and subscribe to it in the Micro Frontend Applications. [Here's an example](https://medium.com/@manivel45/event-emitter-vs-subject-cross-component-communication-8934376605e1)

I hope that gives you a couple additional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same scenario where i have to pass the data from one micro-app to another.
and after lot of R&D i found that event based communication is the best , where i transfer the data in form on Event Objects.
here is some Example:
For sending data:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('userData', { "detail": { "id": id, ...rec } });
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and for receiving the data on other app is:

```
window.addEventListener("userData", function (e: CustomEvent) {
      this.id = e.detail.id;
      this.country = e.detail.country;
      this.contact = e.detail.contact;
      this.company = e.detail.company;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}.bind(this));
```

This approach does not need the DB communication.

Hope this will resolve your query!!!

#### Happy Coding!!!